# React Native: Is there a way to detect document border and change the overlay colour if document inside a frame by using react native camera?

Tags: android, react-native

I am a newbie to react-native. I am currently trying to implement the code which can scan and capture image for an ID card. Basically i am able to take image and save to gallery by using react native camera, but i have no idea how to detect the ID card border. I am seeking help which can guide me about the card border detection or some open source library that can implement such function.

Basically, I have already tried to implement [react-native-documentscanner-android](https://github.com/andreluisjunqueira/react-native-documentscanner-android) and [rn-doc-scanner-android](https://github.com/Diastorm/rn-doc-scanner-android) library. But react-native-documentscanner-android library i failed to implement and the rn-doc-scanner-android is without card border detection function.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";

export default class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
 }
  state = {
    barcodes: [],
  }
render(){
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const maskRowHeight = Math.round((height - 500) / 20);
    const maskColWidth = (width - 300) / 2;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
           ref={ref => {
             this.camera = ref;
           }}
           style={{
             flex: 1,
             width: '100%',
             justifyContent: "center"
           }}
         > 
         <View style={styles.maskOutter}>
            <View style={[{ flex: maskRowHeight  }, styles.maskRow, styles.maskFrame]} />
             <View style={[{ flex: 30 }, styles.maskCenter]}>
             <View style={[{ width: maskColWidth }, styles.maskFrame]} />
             <View style={styles.maskInner} />
            <View style={[{ width: maskColWidth }, styles.maskFrame]} />
          </View>
        <View style={[{ flex: maskRowHeight }, styles.maskRow, styles.maskFrame]} />
      </View>         
      </RNCamera>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#2E8B57', margin: 5}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
takePicture = async() => {
  if (this.camera) {
    const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
    const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
    console.log(data.uri);
    ToastAndroid.show(data.uri, ToastAndroid.LONG);
    if(data.uri!= null){
      console.log('not null')
    }else{
      console.log('null')
    }
    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri);
  }

};
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#2E8B57",
    overflow: 'hidden',
    //width: 350,
    //height: 150,  
},
  camera: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center"
},
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  maskOutter: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  maskInner: {
    width: 300,
    //height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: '#DC143C',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  maskFrame: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,1,1,0.6)',
  },
  maskRow: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  maskCenter: { flexDirection: 'row' },
});
```

Comment: i am also struggling for this but still not found any thing